# How spending same coins both at BCC and BTC blockchains prevented?

Tags: blockchain, doublespend, bitcoin-cash

`------X--.---------- BTC Blockchain
              \
               .--------- BCC Blockchain`

Let's say that we have some BTC coins from a transaction at block X. And, there are two blockchains now. Is spending these coins at both blockcoins prevented? Are there any BTC/BCC cross check for double spending?

Answer (score 0):

This is from their FAQ.

Bitcoin Cash transactions use a new flag SIGHASH_FORKID, which is non standard to the legacy blockchain.  This prevents Bitcoin Cash transactions from being replayed on the Bitcoin blockchain and vice versa.

Comment: I'm not talking about replaying a transaction. What I ask is what would happen if someone creates two different transactions for two different blockchains, using the same private key.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question